# How can I run the application without internet?

Tags: flutter

I am making a new application with Flutter. Products are listed on the web with api. But I wonder,

The user opened the application and all products from json appeared in the application. Then I want him to see the same products when he closes the internet. How can I do this, what do I have to investigate?

Answer (score 0):

for offline viewing:

1. Using [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) for storing image and text (json)

or

2. Using [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) for image caching & [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) for storing text (json)

Comment: Thank you your answer. But is it okay to store 300+ product images and data with sqflite ?

Comment: sure~ sqflite is powerful enough for that, at least most stable one~